# CalEvent with IsAllDay=TRUE gets me in trouble with timezone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timezone, nsdate, nscalendar

I have a TimeZone problem with allday events in CalCalendar:

```
- (BOOL)setDayType:(NSString *)type 
            forDay:(NSDate *)date;
{
    NSError *err = nil;
    CalEvent *e = [CalEvent event];
    [e setTitle:type];
    [e setIsAllDay:YES];
    [e setStartDate:date];
    [e setEndDate:[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:1]];
    [e setCalendar:[self calendar]];
    if ( ![[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] saveEvent:e span:CalSpanThisEvent error:&err] )
    {
...
```

Let's say I set the date at January 2nd, 2012, with a time of 00:00:00. I am at GMT+2, so timezone +0200. My date object reports 1-1-2012, 22:00:00, at GMT, as per this NSLog output:

```
"Set daytype ptd on 2012-01-01 22:00:00 +0000"
```

and *also* generates the allday even on January 1st!!

How can I make sure that I set the allday event in the correct day, *for all timezones*? I could easily add three hours but that will not work worldwide!

Comment: I am now adding to the date like this: `date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]secondsFromGMT]];`. It's not what it should be, though. Does anyone have a better suggestion? I want the date that I feed CalEvent to be represented in my systemTimeZone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `date` is on the correct day in the current time zone, you can use it as-in.

The "problem" that you see is caused because if you *print the stored date via NSLog* (or in the debugger) it will always **show** you GMT time because `NSDate` has no knowledge of which timezone that you are in.

However, since `date` is a specific point in time, when you format it for the user (using a date formatter), it will show the correct date and time, no matter what the time zone is, as long as it stays consistent.

The only situation where you will need to worry about adding/subtracting time like you mention is if you need a point in time which is the same date across *multiple time zone's*.

**EDIT:**
So it looks like iCal uses GMT time to store everything, so you need to create your date in the GMT timezone.  If you need help with this, post your code where you create your `NSDate` and I'll be happy to point you in the right direction.

Comment: The real problem that I have, is that my all-day event is created on the **first** of january, while it should be the second. My system timezone GMT+2 translates "00:00 on the 2nd" to "22:00 on the 1st". Of course, I am setting the `CalEvent` using `[event setStartDate date]`, and never print the stored date at all! I removed the NSLog statement from the post since it distracts from the real issue....

Comment: Regarding the edit from inafziger: that does sound reasonable. I am a little confused still, though. Let's take the example from the question. If I convert that to a GMT all-day event by adding 2 hours, and the "time zone" functionality of ICal is turned on, it might still work for me. But I prefer a solution that will work all around the world. It is also frustrating (and hard to understand) that I need to work around this; I am more likely to do something wrong than that there is an inconsistency in the API...

Comment: It looks like I'll do it by workarounds when using CalendarStore.h. In 10.8, the EventKit will be available for OSX which should solve these problems. I'll just hang in there, using dirty tricks to get things going for now, and upgrade asap.... Thanks lnafziger!